# Load Partial Template Ajax - With Grails

Tags: ajax, templates, grails, partial

I am creating a grails webapp, and have the main index gsp, and there are several common components that will be common across most of the pages on the site that I am using partial templates for.

Each partial template will be quite isolated and contain very different information, so each one should be getting info from different controllers.

What I want is on page loading, for each partial template to make a call to a controller to load the required content - Im hoping there is some tag I can easily place in my partial templates specifying a controller/action that will automatically call the controllers on load.

Is this possible?

**----EDIT-----**

Also, one of the partial templates' controllers will be pulling back information from a web service that can take some time, so it would be good if i could also load these templates asynchronously..

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what the [<g:include>](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/include.html) Tag is for. It's very useful by itself but even more if combined with the [springcache plugin](http://gpc.github.com/grails-springcache/docs/guide/index.html) and using page fragment caching.
Since the include calls a regular action in a  controller you can also consume it by an ajax call.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! that looks like just what I need, however, I have included <g:include controller="web" action="getNews" /> in my partial templates .GSP and the controller method does not seem to be getting called - is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Also, any chance you can point me to an ajax example using the include tag?  Thanks again!

Comment: Depends on your usecase: if you want to call an action that is intended to be included by some other action also via an ajax call, you should use http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html. If the result of an ajax call should include some other action, g:include should be used in the gsp infoked by the ajax call.