# Grails g:include tag to include controller call

Tags: templates, grails, include, partial

I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345281/load-partial-template-ajax-with-grails) I have a new grails app and the index page is made up of several partial templates.  Each of my partial templates need to load data from a different controller, the suggested solution was to use the  tag - I have tried this but seeing nothing happen, and having searched the web I cant find any fully functioning examples of this in action.

Here is my partial template _newsFeed.gsp:

```
<div id="news_feed">
<g:include controller="news" action="latestsNews" /></div>
```

and my controller NewsController.groovy:

```
class NewsController {

def latestsNews = {
    println "in controller"
    [news: "News Headline!"]
}
```

In the above example, Im just trying to confirm that the controller is being called (which is why the println is there) - but im never getting anything.

Can someone point me towards a working example or explain if i am missing something?

Thanks

Comment: would you mind showing the page code where you render the template?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything major wrong with your code.  You are missing a closing brace in your NewsController, but I suspect that was just a typo.  I just tested the following:

```
class HomeController {

   def showMessage = {
     println "Showing message"
     [message: 'this is a message']
   }
}
```

showMessage.gsp just has ${message} in it.  And then in my index.gsp

```
<g:include controller="home" action="showMessage" />
```

I get the correct response.  Is everything else in your view rendering correctly, are you sure the page with the includes is actually getting called/rendered?

Answer (score -1):

When invoking http://localhost:8080/myapp/home/showMessage can you see the log messages in your console ? Please make sure of that first.
The use of the tag is correct and I used it many times ago.

However the use of this tag is not recommended because you perform many controller calls for each request. You can use instead  to render a template without invoking a second controller.

Comment: There are specific cases when it is desirable to use the include tag, especially for caching page fragments; I have used it extensively without any issues.